# Can one use Break inside Switch?

Tags: evaluation, documentation

The documentation for [`Switch`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) states that "You can use `Break`, `Return`, and `Throw` in `Switch`". However, I evaluate the following in 13.2:

```
b = True;
Switch[
 b,
 True, Break[]; Print@"true"
]
```

and receive the message

> Break::nofwd No enclosing For, While, or Do found for Break[].

and the result

```
Hold[Break[]]
```

Is this an error in the documentation?

Comment: Can you explain why you need a Break in your Switch?

Comment: It does look like a problem with the documentation. It's not clear where any of these flow-of-control functions will land if called from inside switch. Another example: `In[24]:= Module[{b = True},
 Switch[b, True, Return["xxx"]; Print@"true"];
 Print["after switch"];
 ]

Out[24]= Return["xxx"]` So it returned from `Nodule` rather than just from the `Switch`. All quite murky to me.

Comment: Interestingly, the documentation for `Switch` mentions `Break` even in [version 1](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/list503.pdf), even though [`Break`](https://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v1/contents/list53.pdf) mentions only `For` and `While`.

Comment: Looks like an error in the documentation. I would report it to support@wolfram.com

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I do not need the functionality, I was just curious after reading the documentation, and wanted to make sure there wasn't something I was failing to understand. I think I understand how they work w.r.t. Module and Do and such, but wasn't sure why or how these control flow functions would work in Switch.

Answer (score -8):

It is not an error in the documentation.

```
Until[True, b = True; Switch[b, True, Break[]; Print["true"]]]
```

Does not generate an output.

I have had nearly six decades of experience dealing with users who have followed this pattern: write some buggy code, submit it to a computer, receive error, and arrive for help demanding that the computer be fixed. I opine that this is another case of the pattern. [Switch](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) does say: "You can use Break, Return, and Throw in Switch." Switch's documentation does *not* say that that usage within Switch can avoid [Break](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Break.html)'s documentation which says: "... exits the nearest enclosing Do, For, Until or While."

The questioner wrote buggy code. In my experience, people generally will *not* attribute an issue to themselves, they instead blame someone or something else, such as documentation. I demonstrated proper usage. I admit my original answer is terse. *Break* does work to break out of a *Switch* to an outer container, such as *Until* in my example, as no error message was generated.

Comment: I don’t follow this.

Comment: Until[True,b=True;Switch[b,
True,
Print["Break next"];Break[];Print["true"],
_,Print["Something else"]]]  generates Break next. Read the original question!

Comment: Slightly more elaborate test: `c = False;
Until[c === True, b = True; 
 Switch[b, True, Print["Break next"]; Break[]; Print["true"]]; 
 Print["past switch"];]

Break next` Which shows the `Break` broke from `Until` rather than `Switch`. If it only exited the `Switch` it would be an infinite loop of printing. The issue is whether `Break` breaks from `Switch` or, in your example, breaks from an outer construct...

Comment: ... and a simpler test shows it does not care to break from `Switch`: `In[830]:= b = True; Switch[b, True, Print["Break next"]; Break[]; 
 Print["true"]];

During evaluation of In[830]:= Break next

During evaluation of In[830]:= Break::nofwd: No enclosing For, While, Until or Do found for Break[].

Out[830]= Hold[Break[]]`...

Comment: ...(Did you seriously think I had not read the question?!)

Comment: The edited version is sort of playing with semantics (both English and that of the Wolfram Language). I didn't downvote it, but I did flag it. It just doesn't get at the actual matter, which is that yes (to the original poster), the documentation is misleading.

Comment: One can use Break/Return/Throw inside of any other construct and get similar behavior as with Switch, and yet I don't read "You can use Break, Return, and Throw in **Plot**", for example. So, I suppose it's literally true that this documentation isn't  _wrong_, but it is anomalous and unhelpful.

Comment: It is misguided, but within bounds of the forum, to hold the belief that the  documentation makes sense. Me, I'm pretty sure it was written with the thought that `Switch` is akin to the "switch" statement in C (which is not at all the case in terms of fall-throughs). What is out of bounds is your claim that the poster is blaming the program/documentation and not taking responsibility for the possibly erroneous code. That simply isn't what happened.

Comment: 1) I opine that the others are playing with semantics. The question is quite clear: the questioner apparently did understand the documentation. 2) Leaving a control structure abruptly is a common need in programming; not all exits need or shout be from the control structure. 3) I just checked. Break[] works as exprected from within Plot. Until[True, Plot[x, {x, -1, 1}, 
     Prolog -> 
      (Print["Just before Break[]"]; 
       Break[]; Print[
        "Just before Break[]"])]; 
    Print["Normal exit"]; ]; 
  Print["\"Until\" exit"];  Gives "Just before Break[]" and "Until" exit.

Comment: I have programmed in languages in which the switch case clause falls through unless explicitly exited and languages where only zero or one case clause was executed. Please, see the discussion in [*Switch statement*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switch_statement). In Mathematica, Break in Switch does work as documented in Mathematica.

Comment: Again, no. The Break exited the outer Until, not Plot. There’s a difference.

Comment: @IAmANaïf "I just checked. Break[] works as expected from within Plot". My point was the the documentation for Plot doesn't mention anything about Break. If it's not necessary there, why was it necessary in the documentation for Switch? The same comment that appeared in Switch should appear in the documentation for every function, because it works the same way for every function.

Comment: Yes, Break immediately interrupts evaluation and looks for an enclosing Do/For/Until/While (and generates warnings if not found). But that's not anything special to do with Switch. I could evaluate `a[Break[]]` and get the same result as with the Switch with a Break in it. Break does what it does regardless of which head it's most closely associated with. It just so happens that when you use it inside loop structures, the effect is useful and sort of intuitive.

Comment: @lericr Exactly! Your first comment) I conject that it because many new Mathematica user come from [computer languages with implicit case clause fallthough, e.g., C](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/162615/why-dont-languages-use-explicit-fall-through-on-switch-statements). They do not that Mathematica *Switch* clauses* **do not** fallthrough. Your second question) One *minor* amendment: "... when you use it inside <s>loop</s> *control* structures ...".  Switch is a control structure in C and it is a flow structure in Mathematica. 3) This should move to chat.

Comment: @IAmANaïf As best as I can tell, you're not only missing the point, but misunderstanding the substance. Maybe it's just a communcation problem, but I basically disagree with all of your analyses (as best as I can undersand them anyway).

Comment: @lericr Yes, it is a communications problem. But, it not at my end. I have worked with over 100 computer languages so far, 58 years of systems level experience, and have been acknowedged by several full professors as doing doctorate level work, 18 years of college, about 80 semester hours of computer science semester-hours of masters level and 3 of doctorate level. [Also commonly attributed to Voltaire is the saying “I may disagree with you, but I defend to the death your right to say it.”](https://mtsu.edu/first-amendment/article/1263/voltaire).

Comment: @lecicr It might be prudent at this point to admit defeat (to yourself, anyway) and walk (or better, run) away. Like I did.